# Python: Matplotlib scatterplot has an upper limit on the number of handles returned (not returning all handles to properly print legend)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot, scatter

I am using matplotlib to make a scatterplot. My data has x and y coordinates of the points I am plotting as well as a "count" value which takes on values from 1 to 29. In order to represent the "count" in the legend, I am using 3 different ways as given below.

a) Size of the scatter point

b) Color of the scatter point

c) X mark on alternative "count"

Since there are 29 counts, I am expecting 29 entries in the legend. However, it seems there is a cap for the number of legend entries at 8. Is there a way to ensure that I can show all the 29 legend entries. The code I have so far is given below

```
point = cluster_actual_crashes
# point.geometry gives x and y coordinates 
# point['count'] gives the count value for that data point

scatter = plt.scatter(point.geometry.x, point.geometry.y,
                   edgecolors = 'black',
                   linewidths = 2,
                   c=point['count'],
                   s=100*point['count'].values^2,
                   cmap = 'hsv',#Cyclic colormapshttps://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html 
                   alpha = 0.5) 
# point_plus are the points which are marked with 'X'
point_plus = point[point['count'].isin(point['count'].value_counts().index[::2])]
scatter_plus = plt.scatter(point_plus.geometry.x, point_plus.geometry.y,
                           marker = "x",
                           s=80*point_plus['count'].values^2 ) 

# https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html
handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop='sizes')
handles2, _ = scatter.legend_elements(prop='colors')
handles_plus, _ = scatter_plus.legend_elements(prop='sizes')
handles_final = []
for i, handle in enumerate(handles):
    handles[i].set_c(handles2[i].get_c())
    handles[i].set_linewidth(2)
    handles[i].set_markeredgecolor('black')
    if ((i+1)%2 == 1):
        # print(int((i-1)/2))
        handles_final.append((handles[i],handles2[i], handles_plus[int((i-1)/2)]))
    else:
        handles_final.append((handles[i],handles2[i]))
        # handles[i].set_markeredgecolor('red')
labels = [str(i) for i in set(point['count'].values)]
# Add a title to legend with title keyword
plt.legend(handles_final, labels, title='Number of Crashes',
           loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5),
           labelspacing=2,
           borderpad=1.5,
           title_fontsize=titlefontsize*0.9,
           fontsize = titlefontsize*0.9)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If c is set to an array of integers, then a maximum of 15 legend entries is possible.

```
c = np.arange(len(15)) + 1
```

Note that if you pass any 'foreign' value in this array other than 1 thru' 15, not only is the value ignored, but the legend will contain only 8 handles and labels at most.

You can have an array of length larger than 15, but each value has to be in [1..15] and only the first 15 values will be picked up for legend entry creation.

Given that you have 29 data points, I would suggest using two legends. Each legend can use colors running from 1 thru' 15, and each set can use its own distinct marker.

I have tried other color labels (for reference, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colors.html?highlight=x11%20css4%20xkcd). While this allows for the specification of more than 15 colors, in all cases I was unsuccessful in having a legend created.

*NOTE:*
I'm a newbie to python and matplotlib. I encountered this problem for the first time myself today while trying to label 18 data points.

Perhaps it's not wise to have more than 15 series on a single plot for UX/readability?

Perhaps **annotation** is the right way to label more than 15 points on a scatterplot?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of labels in your dataset, you can bypass the limit by explicitly passing `num` to `legend_elements`. This will force extraction of the right number of legend items.